# why gmail smtp reply message size limit is different

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, gmail

According to google documentations with following link  https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en  , message size limitation for inbound emails is **50 MB** but as i was testing gmail smtp server there was a reply as follow:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP p14-20020a7bcc8e000000b003c6f289e99esi5592406wma.88 - gsmtp
ehlo test.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [46.209.208.220]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

From above output it is saying that gmail.com mail server is accepting up to **150 MB** so my question is what is the correct limit ? and why the smtp response is different ?

Comment: You would need to ask someone at Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test has determined the maximum message size that the servers at mx.google.com will receive, but those servers aren't likely hosting the actual user mailboxes. The servers at mx.google.com sit at the ingress for inbound email and then pass that email onto the servers that host the actual mailboxes. The servers that host the actual mailboxes may limit the maximum inbound message size to 50MB, or it may be that the mailboxes themselves restrict the maximum inbound message size to 50MB. You haven't discovered a contradiction in Google's terms. You've merely discovered the maximum message size that the servers at mx.google.com will receive.

What you've discovered is common. The servers at the ingress are configured for the maximum inbound message size that the email system as a whole will accept. Those message size limits can, and often are, then further limited internally, dependent upon where the email is destined. It's not uncommon to see SMTP servers at the ingress of the email system set to a specific size limit and then to have the mailbox hosting servers or mailboxes themselves configured for a lower message size limit.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is whatever they *do* accept and is **likely to have changed and change again**, so for a current answer on that just *try* it or ask Google.

As to why someone would document a different limit than what their MX say in the SMTP session: If they announce a larger limit than what they are willing to accept later on, they can

1. apply a consistent limit to 7-bit and 8-bit transfer (which is nice to reduce confusion with [senders expecting to be always able to send](https://serverfault.com/a/1104057/250204) 50MiB, regardless of **transfer-encoding overhead**) and they can
2. have their help **page URL from their SMTP response** (eg. `550 5.7.1` https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584) appear in the non-delivery notification, which won't happen if the sending server gives up right away.